# EC2 board advice

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, webmin

this is my first post. 
I wanted a advice on my aws services. Last week I purchased an EC2 T2 medium where I installed a Lamp and webmin server. All worked well until yesterday. Because on the server there is an online newspaper that does a great job of visiting, reaching 400 people online on the site the server has blocked and I lost at least 500 more visits at the same time as the server was unavailable. 
Apparently, it was a matter of CPU credits. 
Now I've gone to a C4 Large instance, so I wanted to ask who's more experienced than me, if the choice is right and if the server blockage problem does not happen anymore.

I hope I have been clear and apologetic for my English. 
Thank you

Comment: When you say "Apparently, it was a matter of CPU credits", how did you reach this conclusion? What monitoring do/did you have in place?

Comment: Because I saw that in the reports of the CPU where credits were shown, the values went down quickly. Then, in fact, the site in question never fell, but had slowed down a lot since it had total blocking moments. For this I said that apparently it seemed a problem of CPU credits.

Comment: The CPU credit model is the reason the t2 instance class is so inexpensive.  It is a good solution for many workloads, but you have to be aware of your application's demands for CPU cycles and monitor the credit balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the details provided it sounds like you have enough CPU bound traffic that you do need a dedicated and consistent CPU. C4 instances are a good choice for compute intensive work and should help you. Additionally, I would recommend running your workload on instances in an auto scaling group with and Elastic Load Balancer. This will provide better scalability and availability. You should also setup a CloudWatch monitor to be alerted if your servers encounter similar issues in the future. I've linked some additional details below.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-cloudwatch.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-cloudwatch-createalarm.html